# Upgrading Carbon Powershell DevOps library ignores prefix option for import module

Tags: powershell, devops

1. I am not in devops but it got to me
2. we are using Carbon, import-module with prefix Carbon, so we call procedures ie: Grant-CarbonPrivilege
3. Import-Module -Prefix 'Carbon' -Name 'Carbon' -ErrorAction 'Stop'

i would be calling carbon Install-CarbonService, while calling our function Install-Service.....
And calling it like this was causing an issue....

But as it seems Carbon says No.

Did anyone encounter this? Is there any good solution? or do we have to rename our procedures to be safe?

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates the issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help on how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a case of a powershell newbie solving powershell issues.
Maybe this answer helps someone else...

What happened:
One of our DEV reacted to a message about one function getting deprecated and changed call from XXX-Carbon to XXX-C.
This caused Powershell to explicitly load Carbon and overwrite our function.

After changed the call to XXX-CarbonC all is ok and works....

Sorry Carbon, not your fault.
I hope this helps some other newbie in similar case